# Hot Reload shows blank screen in Electron Svelte with svelte-routing

Tags: javascript, electron, svelte, hot-reload

I am working on an Electron.js application, utilizing Svelte as my frontend framework.

I'm using hot reload with chikidar, but every time I reload it shows a white blank screen, and I get an error in the devtools: `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///`

I think this is because I use the svelte-routing package, and do something wrong with it.
When I first start the app, the window location is :`file:///path/to/project/public/index.html`,
but after the first svelte-routing link is used, it changes to: `file:///`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works fine with this electron starter pack : https://github.com/nateshmbhat/svelte-electron-ts-starter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's an electron app, url doesn't really matter, I store the current page name in a Svelte store, and I have an if-else block for choosing which page to display